# Unpacking source Debian package that has a tar.xz

Tags: debian, source, packaging

I've download the `.tar.gz`, `.dsc` and `.diff.gz` of the *bash* package from Wheezy: https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/bash. Then I ran `dpkg-source -x` on the `dsc` file to unpack it, and this is the result:

```
$ ls -l
total 2696
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pgimeno pgimeno 2748840 Dec 30  2012 bash-4.2dfsg.tar.xz
drwxrwxr-x 3 pgimeno pgimeno    4096 Apr  3 23:36 debian
```

**UPDATE: I can extract the archive manually, the problem is not that. Please read carefully below. I've added emphasis on some key sentences.**

That has confused me. What should I do to get a fully unpacked archive *with the Debian patches applied*, so that I can *work on the source and produce a modified package that builds?* Do I have to unpack it myself and apply the patches by hand? If so, to what directory should I unpack it? The default after running `tar -xf bash-4.2dfsg.tar.xz` is `bash-4.2`, should I leave it like that or move the files to the main directory? And then what?

Comment: Very similar to http://askubuntu.com/questions/92328/how-do-i-uncompress-a-tarball-that-uses-xz

Comment: Not really. I can unpack the tar.xz by hand (as I indicate in the last part of the question), that's not the problem. The problem is that I'm supposed to get a fully unpacked source that I can work on, not an archive, and the one I extract by hand lacks the patches from debian/patches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The central place that records what to do with a source package is [`debian/rules`](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-source.html#s-debianrules). It's a makefile, and a few targets are mandatory or standardized, including `build`, which will of necessity unpack and patch any source archive, and `patch`, which should unpack and patch any source archive. Many packages use [helper scripts](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/developers-reference/best-pkging-practices.html#bpp-debian-rules), the main ones being [debhelper](https://packages.debian.org/en/sid/debhelper) (`dh_*` and the newer `dh` frontend) and [cdbs](http://build-common.alioth.debian.org/cdbs-doc.html).

The bash package in wheezy uses a few debhelper scripts and doesn't provide a `patch` target. It doesn't provide an `unpack` target either (an common convention), but it does provide some targets that it uses internally:

```
make -f debian/rules bash_src=bash unpack-bash
make -f debian/rules bash_src=bash patch-bash
```

Comment: So I take it that there's no standard way of unpacking a package that comes in this form? Knowing that there isn't one helps too. I gather that the configure trick in my answer would be more compatible across packages, without needing to analyze `debian/rules`, is that right? If so, adding that to your answer will help others too.

Comment: @PedroGimeno There's no standard, it's part of the package's build process. An `unpack` target and a `patch` target are common conventions, but not universal. The `bash-configure` rule name isn't standard either: the common convention would be `configure`, not `PACKAGENAME-configure`.

Answer (score 0):

valdyn from `irc.oftc.net` helped me find one solution, which was to run:

```
debian/rules bash-configure
```

It does some extra work and leaves some directories that are not part of the source, but at least it unpacks it and applies the patches, so that allows me to work on the patched source now. As I suspected, the destination directory was not intended to be `bash-4.2` as unpacking by hand did, but just `bash`.

But this feels like a dirty hack. I'm still looking for the "right" solution, one that just leaves the source ready for a normal build while still allowing me to work on it first, as with most packages, without needing to do a configure run.